# When i launch android emulator its different with android studio. How it solve?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

[**When i launch android emulator its different with android studio. How it solve?**

[image]

**Also i have error:Changes were not applied.Added variable(s) does not support value initialization: Adding static primitive com.maksymb.geteat.R$id.linearLayout**

**Session 'app': Changes were not applied.
Added variable(s) does not support value initialization: Adding static primitive com.maksymb.geteat.R$id.linearLayout**

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/f1_header_image"
    android:layout_width="3dp"
    android:layout_height="371dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">


</FrameLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="106dp"
    android:contentDescription="GetEat"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="155dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="99dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
    android:text="Login"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp" />

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/til_login_email"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
    android:hint="Email id"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_login_email"
    android:layout_width="389dp"
    android:layout_height="66dp"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:text="abc@gmail.com"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="5dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="332dp" />

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/til_login_password"
    android:layout_width="390dp"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    android:hint="Password"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="5dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="388dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_login_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:text="123456" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Login"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/til_login_password"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/til_login_password"
    app:layout_goneMarginEnd="16dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_register"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="Register"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="222dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="585dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_dnt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="Don't have an account?"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/tv_register"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="70dp" />
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Answer (score 0):

You have not setup your constrains and using fixed positions,

remove `tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"` and let the errors to show up

then remove all `tools:layout_editor_absoluteX` `tools:layout_editor_absoluteY`

`tools` name space only has an affect on android studio preview

to implement and use constrains follow the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout)